# Physical laws limiting the size and energy density of battery/capacitor

Tags: electromagnetism, material-science, batteries

The size and energy/power density of battery are always under active research and it would be nice to have small-sized battery with high energy density as well, but this seems to be nearly impossible.

I noticed that scientists have made [microscopic supercapacitors](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-021-24863-6) while he power density isn’t very high (seems it can only sustain nA of currents). And there are very impressive [graphene batteries](https://medium.com/swlh/the-next-generation-of-batteries-dca0d931755b) with energy density as high as 1000 Wh/kg, [other battery with similar energy density](https://www.v2charge.com/innolith-claims-1000-wh-kg-battery-breakthrough/), and [graphene supercapacitor](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/28854156/) with energy density as high as 150 Wh/kg. But there size are often not that microscopic (correct me if wrong).

So I wonder by physical law and current technology is it possible to make a battery/supercapacitor with high energy density while microscopic (say millimetres in scale) size? For instance, can we shrink a graphene battery with energy density 1000 Wh/kg to several mm^3 volume while keeping the energy density unchanged?

Comment: Present science fiction (what you’re wondering, is often tomorrows reality, but I’m voting to close your post because this site only  deals with mainstream physics

Comment: @BobD thanks for the comment. But I don’t think I am asking about sci-fi stuff. Instead my question is about how physical laws restrict the size of battery, if any.

Answer (score 1):

The chemical reaction in a battery or the breakdown voltage of the dielectric in a capacitor do limit the energy density. The only limit on size is the cost.  In the fifties I worked with a synchrotron. The room sized magnet was in an oscillating circuit with a room sized bank of capacitors.

Comment: What about the other way? How small can batteries be while maintaining high energy density?

Comment: I'm guessing a nano-bot runs on a battery.